# Why appears ` disciplined convex programming ruleset` error when using cvxpy

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, quadratic-programming

When I run this using cvxpy (`cost` is my objective function):

```
x = cp.Variable((4,4), integer=False)

for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,3):
        cost += (x[i][j] / x[i][j+1] + 5)**2
```

It gets error:

```
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
var3[0, 0:2][0] / var3[0, 0:2][1]
var3[1, 0:2][0] / var3[1, 0:2][1]
```

Why does this appear?  I have checked the DCP ruleset as it said: http://cvxr.com/cvx/doc/dcp.html#quadforms
.  But i'm also not sure.

BTW, if i turn the division to log, like `cost += (log(x[i][j]) - log(x[i][j+1]) + 5)**2`, it will also give a error:`NameError: name 'log' is not defined var1`, seems the content in log can't be a variable.

So is there a solution to address this? Or how can i transform my objective function in cvxpy to do this?

Comment: CVXPY is for convex problems only. The first sentence at https://www.cvxpy.org/: "*CVXPY is an open source Python-embedded modeling language for convex optimization problems.*"

Comment: ``x/y`` is not a convex function of two variables ``x,y``. Neither is ``(x/y+5)^2``. To apply ``log`` to a cvxpy variable you would have to use ``cp.log(...)``, since Python's ``log`` obviously doesn't know howto deal with cvxpy objects. But similar nonconvexity issue will occur.

Comment: So this is what kind of function? I saw cvxpy has Disciplined quasiconvex programming (DQCP)[https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dqcp/index.html#dqcp-problems] and Disciplined Geometric Programming(DGP)[https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dgp/index.html]. It seems in these two, I can realise the multiple or division of two variables.

Comment: Also, can cvxpy only solve convex optimization problems? In its document seems concave problems is also suitable.

Comment: You might fit DGP but that of course depends on the rest of your problem, which you never showed. Why not write on https://or.stackexchange.com/ with your FULL problem and ask for advice for a suitable problem type/solver. Asking these partial questions will keep you in the blind. Maximizing(concave) and Minimizing(convex) is the same.

Comment: I have posted my whole question in [https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9413/how-to-solve-this-mixed-integer-quadratic-program-using-cvxpy-or-other-method]. I wish you can have a look on it. I'm very grateful for that!